# Insert Record from AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Insert Record to elasticsearch from AJAX - Not working
I am able to search in elastic search with AJAX. But I am not able insert
record with AJAX. Can someone help me..

```
var attr={
"username":"username",
"password":"password"
};

$.ajax( {
url: 'http://localhost:9200/'+'objects'+'/'+'saved_queries1/1/',
type: 'POST',
crossDomain: true,
dataType: 'json',
data: JSON.stringify(attr),
success: function(response) {
console.log("SUCCESS");
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
console.log("ERROR");
}
});

}
```

Comment: What's the error you getting?

Comment: Is your URL correct? It looks like you are selecting an item ("/1"), not inserting.

Comment: @OrAssayag ajax error [bad request]

Comment: Are you sure the URL exists? What is the result of 'http://localhost:9200/'+'objects'+'/'+'saved_queries1/1/'.
check with FileZilla, do direct request and simulate a direct call, without the ajax, to see if responses.